# Inheritance problems when using T types in base forms

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, .net-core, inheritance

```
public partial class BaseListForm<TEntity> : RibbonForm where TEntity : CoreBaseEntity {}
```

I gave TEntity to my BaseListForm and predicate from CoreBaseEntity,

```
 public partial class AddressTypeForm_List : BaseListForm<Si_AddressType> // Si_AddressType inherits from CoreBaseEntity {}
```

and other forms inherits from BaseListForm looks like this,

```
public class ShowListForms<TForm> where TForm : BaseListForm<CoreBaseEntity> {}
```

i have a class called ShowListForms where i use for specific purposes,
it also inherits from BaseListForm.

```
 ShowListForms<AddressTypeForm_List>.ShowListForm();
```

I am having this problem when i use form in ShowListForm.

ERROR ;

Error   CS0311  The type 'AddressType.AddressTypeForm_List' cannot be used as type parameter 'TForm' in the generic type or method 'ShowListForms'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'AddressType.AddressTypeForm_List' to 'Models.Base.CoreBaseEntity>'.

Thanks for the help.

If i use **BaseListForm** instead of **BaseListForm<Si_AddressType>** in second code part the problem resolves but i need a workaround.

Comment: Please include your code as text (formatted as code) and not as images.

Comment: *I have a class called ShowListForms* <= Share the code of the class, to let us know what `ShowListForms<AddressTypeForm_List>.ShowListForm();` does.

Comment: @RezaAghaei 
its basically doing this.
var frm = (TForm)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TForm));
frm.Show();

Comment: @batuhanaslantürk it doesn't give any idea about the ShowListForms<AddressTypeForm_List>. Please share the code of this class. It's not clear what are the generic constraints there, why the generic is for the class and not for the method, if `ShowListForm` is static or instance. and etc. You probably have an obvious mistake, because a conversion *'AddressType.AddressTypeForm_List' to 'Models.Base.CoreBaseEntity>'* doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly you have to carry the TEntity everywhere in the subclasses if you want this to work.

The problem is that `public class ShowListForms<TForm> where TForm : BaseListForm<CoreBaseEntity> {}` doesn't have any TEntity passed to `BaseListForm`, so it expects that TForm is something that extends exactly `BaseListForm<CoreBaseEntity>`

You can do it like this:

```
public class ShowListForms<TForm, TEntity> 
where TForm : BaseListForm<TEntity> 
where TEntity : CoreBaseEntity {}
```

Not it will look a bit more complicated when you call it but I think it should work.

```
 ShowListForms<AddressTypeForm_List,Si_AddressType>.ShowListForm();
```